# I can't use the database connection outside the constructor, why?

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

Why can't I execute a query outside the constructor? I can't use the variables I declared in the constructor. Why not? Do I have to put the database connection in a method with parameters?

```
public class main extends javax.swing.JFrame
{
    DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();

    public main()
    {
        initComponents();
        try
        {
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/project", "root", "password");
            Statement stat = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet resultaat = stat.executeQuery(query);

            while (resultaat.next())
            {
                model.addElement(resultaat.getString(2));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

con is withing your constructor scope . Use

`Connection con;`

as class variable and in constructor

```
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/project","root","password");
```

use this only. Do same for required variables. Which you need to use through out the class.

Answer (score 2):

> i cant use the variables i declared in the constructor. why not?

Because, as they are declared inside the constructor they are **confined to that scope**. you can't access them outside your constructor. If you want to use them outside the constructor, make them as **instance variables** which you should be doing in the first place.

Your class should like something like this:

```
public class DBConnection {
  Connection con=null;
  public DBConnection() {
    initComponents();
    try {
      conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/project","root","password");
    }
    catch(SQLException ex) {
    }
  }

  public void doDBOps() {
    String yourQuey="whatever";
    PreparedStatement stmnt = this.conn.preparedStatement(yourQuery);
    ResultSet rs = stmnt.executeQuery();
    //rest of your code 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Variables defined inside a method or a constructor are limited to that scope. If you wish to initialize a variable and use it across your class you'll have to turn it into a class field (thus, broadening its scope to the class itself) and, by convention, define a `get` and/or `set` method.

Answer (score 0):

It seems what you are looking overall is a Singleton Class for the Database. You can use this class in other classes to access an existing connection instead of using the `DriverManager` factory to get a new connection object every time.

The sample below is shamelessly stolen from [here](http://www.coderanch.com/t/298222/JDBC/databases/Database-Connection-Singleton)

```
public class DBConnectionSingleton
{
  private static DBConnectionSingleton instance = null;
  private static Connection conn;
  private DBConnectionSingleton()
  {
    String dbDriver = ..
    String url = ..
    String username= ..
    String password = ..
    try
    {
      Class.forName(dbDriver);
      conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfErr)
    {
      cnfErr.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (SQLException err)
    {
      err.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  public static DBConnectionSingleton getInstance()
  {
    if (instance == null)
      return new DBConnectionSingleton();
    else
      return instance;
  }
  public static Connection getConnection()
  {
    return conn;
  }
}
```

Comment: It looks like the singleton `instance` in this example is never initialized...?